# Write to NTFS drive mounted with SMB in OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, ntfs, osx-mountain-lion, smb

I wanna be able to write to an NTFS drive mounted over SMB.

I've tried following [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090913140023382) guide but when I run `diskutil info /Volumes/inetpub` (inetpub being the name of the drive) I get `Could not find disk: /Volumes/inetpub`.

I've also tried some 3rd party software but they didn't seem to work.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.8 and the "Get info" window of the drive looks like [this](http://cl.ly/image/2q1V2A0z1D1t).

Answer (score 2):

As far as your Mac is concerned, that's not an NTFS volume, it's an SMB volume. Macs can write to SMB just fine (as long as the permissions allow writing), so you shouldn't need to do anything special (other than maybe adjusting the permissions on the server).